# Issues With Difficult To Search Questions

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, reopen-closed

I've found this frustrating because this type of question is difficult to search using search engines. I've had to contact the moderators to correct the reason for closure as duplicate because the first time this question was closed, the reason was "asking for recommendation".

Can someone share their opinion about this interaction with Stack Overflow?

Search engines queries:

- https://www.google.com/search?q=%24(()%20%3D%3E%20%7B
- https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjquery%5D+%24%28%28%29+%3D%3E+%7B

Comment: All votes are justified.

Comment: relevant: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/249848/search-using-symbols-is-broken

Comment: My opinion is that comments such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64983206/what-is-the-used-in-the-electron-sample-project-activity-monito#comment114886454_64983206) (now deleted) are unacceptable. Off-site articles such as that one from Quora are usually deturbed and biased on the position of a user who felt entitled for personal help and got offended for just not getting that. A mere rant. Trying to understand and follow our guidelines is good. Showing defamation in our face when you don't do that is not.

Comment: Searching for [this](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&ei=Zdm8X-b4E5Lagwe2y4iAAg&q=%24%28%29+%3D%3E++javascript&oq=%24%28%29+%3D%3E++javascript&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIGCAAQBxAeMgYIABAHEB4yBggAEAcQHjIGCAAQBxAeMgQIABAeMgQIABAeMgQIABAeMgQIABAeMgQIABAeMgQIABAeOgQIABBHOgIIAFDz5gFYhPMBYNr0AWgCcAJ4AIABXIgB7AOSAQE2mAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpesgBCMABAQ&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwimv8nh9ZrtAhUS7eAKHbYlAiAQ4dUDCAw&uact=5) gives me two immediately relevant results on google. (And plenty more below).

Comment: Are immediately relevant, and pieces of the puzzle useful to figure out how to better answer the question. If you were already familiar with those, maybe you should have added more detail to the question. You mentioned your question was "ungoobleable", I was just trying to show that with the appropriate keywords, it's not so hard to get many relevant results.

Comment: The first two results I get are: [one](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrow_function.asp) about "the arrow function" in w3schools, and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2167544/1426539). Immediately I get more SO results where I get [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8228281/1426539). I think someone asking the question you asked would find all of those relevant and useful.

Comment: That's the research needed to answer one's own questions, yes. The other option is copy pasting code in a question and ask other users to say what it does. You said it's was "ungoogleable", I'm just trying to point out that maybe it wasn't so difficult to research. Search engines got pretty good at dealing with this stuff.

Comment: Well considering [the documentation](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) for `ready()` is one of the first 6 results I get (excluding the grouped SO results), where this syntax is explained, I think the search would have been pretty useful. Unless you don't know what an arrow function was (which you don't explain in your question). But for those the first results would have helped as well. Good luck in your future searches! Bye!

Comment: If you knew `$` was jQuery, then looking at https://api.jquery.com/jQuery you could have seen `jQuery( callback )` in the TOC and followed the link to https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-callback - *"Binds a function to be executed when the DOM has finished loading... This function behaves just like `$( document ).ready()`"*.

Comment: This is practically unintelligible. It's certainly not clear what you are asking about what. PS Please don't edit in a way that invalidates reasonable answers already posted.

Answer (score 24):

Downvoting and closing of [that question's initial draft](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64983206/revisions) was completely justified, as it contained an image of code, when it should have included plain text.

I agree that the closure reason that was originally chosen was... odd. That question wasn't seeking a recommendation for an off-site resource. It was asking about a specific syntax used in a programming language, which is a practical programming problem fully within the scope of Stack Overflow. Whether it's Googleable or not is irrelevant.

It does seem like a duplicate, but actually a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7642442/what-does-function-do), which I've now added as the top duplicate target. Note that having a question closed as a duplicate is a natural and expected outcome of asking a syntax question like this. Although they are definitely hard to search for due to practical reasons, they will almost certainly have been asked before, for the same reasons that you're asking it now.

Comment: What do you mean? Why do you assume that you did something wrong? The only thing I see that you did wrong was posting an image of code, instead of actual code.

Comment: @LouisHong to me it seems like the people who voted for the wrong close reason were in the wrong and that nobody linked any duplicates before it was closed. That is not your fault. The only misstep was the image of code which I notified you about and, to your credit, you promptly fixed. This is exactly the type of thing comments are meant to resolve. Yes, the question is hard to search for. Even if it wasn't based on code, some people may miss the correct terminology to search for. This is why we have duplicates - to point them *and future visitors* where the answers are.

Comment: @LouisHong I think there's a second problem beyond the image: it's unclear what you *do* know about the snippet you show. Are you familiar with the arrow function syntax, for example? Do you understand that as a call to a function named `$` with a function parameter? Are you aware that `$` commonly refers to jQuery?

Comment: @LouisHong yes, that's also not very specific (the fact that the accepted answer contains *"can you clarify what you mean"* confirms as much), but it's nearly a decade old and you're asking about the response to *your* question.

Comment: @LouisHong because it gets you to an answer to your question (if that *is* what you were asking, what passing a callback to jQuery does). If it doesn't (and you were actually wondering what `() => {...}` meant, for example), edit your question to clarify and focus what you *were* asking (e.g. in that case *"I know $ means jQuery but I usually see `$(function () {...})` or `$(selector)`, what does this syntax mean?"* - it's still a dupe, but at least then the right one can be selected).

Comment: @LouisHong for 1. it's worth using the *names* of those symbols - search for "dollar" instead of "$", "caret" instead of "^", etc.

Comment: @LouisHong "*so how is linking my question as a duplicate of another violating question in any way better?*" it immediately gives you an answer. Not only one but *many* which have been gathered and refined for literal years. So, you get access to high quality explanations. Closing the question also helps avoid fragmenting this knowledge, as new answers can be posted where the original question is. "*How should one ask this question in it's full glory?*" as you did was fine. Regardless of *how* you ask it, the response is to link it to a duplicate, however. Again *that's not a punishment*.

Comment: @Teemu what? The part that's hidden from other users is just the detail on who voted, the links to the dupes appear for *everyone*. If there's a single dupe target and you're not logged in (IIRC), the system redirects you straight to the target.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Redirects ..? I really need to visit SO as an anonymous user much more often. Though I visited the mentioned question before commenting. Only that I did it with IE, which is not supported anymore, it didn't make any redirecting.

Comment: @Teemu the question being discussed here doesn't have a *single* dupe target, try e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/64982822/3001761.